# How to move the drawn text up when it gets out of the canvas height in Android?

Tags: java, android, canvas, text, paint

I'm building a drawing app in android and I'm stuck with this; when the `Text` is too large it was drawing outside of the `Canvas` width, that's solved now, but the problem is when the text goes out of the canvas height, how can I calculate the whole text height and if it goes out, move it up so it can fit in the screen?

I Already tried with two canvas, and draw on the second canvas so if it goes out i just use canvas.translate(x,y), but still not working.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Android API has the set of layout's classes (package android.text), that implement the rendering of text.

Example:

```
int maxWitdh; // mam witdh of text
StaticLayout layout = new StaticLayout(text, mPaint, maxWidth, Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1, 0, true);

int height = layout.getHeight();

layout.draw(canvas);
```

Comment: Well i tried this and it got better when the text goes out of the screen width, but still not solving my height problem :/, text still goes out of the screen height .

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, with the StaticLayout i got the height of the whole text and compared it with the height of the screen.

```
if (layoutHeight > height - coordinateY){
    secondCanvas.translate(getCoordX(), height-layoutHeight);
}
```

Now it never goes out of the height.